# Include directive in master doc

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In my `conf.py` I have defined the master as `index` ( `index.rst`)

```
# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'
```

When I import a list of rst files using the `.. include:: list.rst` where `list .rst` file is being created dynamically.

```
Project Test
================================

.. include:: list.rst
```

it works fine; but when I add some other rst names in the same `index.rst` it doesn't work, like `static.rst` and `about.rst` in the following declaration :

```
Project Test
================================

.. include:: list.rst

   static
   about
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new file `staticList.rst` and moved all the static rst names.

```
.. toctree::
  :maxdepth: 1

  static
  about
```

and included the `staticList.rst` in the `index.rst` file, it is giving the desired result but slightly broken listing.

```
Project Test
================================

.. include:: list.rst
.. include:: staticList.rst
```